# how to achieve secure communication between 2 websites

Tags: php, security, encryption, openssl, aes

I am preparing communication & data-exchange system between 2 websites, and would like to enhance it using suggestion posted by Stackoverflow community members.

Let me explain how I am doing it right now, by following example.

There are 2 websites

- server-example.com (will be referred now as SE.com)
- client-example.com (will be referred now as CE.com)

Before performing data-exchange between sites, following steps are performed.

- Using openssl_* functions, asynchronous key pairs are generated at SE.com
- Private Key is kept at SE.com
- Public Key is send to CE.com via normal HTTP request (detailed process below)
- Public Key is encoded using json_encode function
- Encoded data is pushed to CE.com

Further,

- Once CE.com receives encoded data, using json_decode function it retrives PublicKey
- CE.com generates a random string (called rkey) using custom function
- rkey is encrypted using openssl_public_encrypt function
- Encrypted data is pushed to SE.com

Further,

- On receiving encrypted data, SE.com de-cryptes it using openssl_private_decrypt
- Now, SE.com has same rkey (as CE.com)

Now, Let's assume that SE.com needs to send following string 'Hello World' to CE.com

Both sites have custom library for AES encryption-decryption.

- SE.com uses rkey with AES encrypt function to generate encrypted text
- Generated encrypted text is encoded using json_encode function and pushed to CE.com

Now, CE.com gets encrypted text

- On receiving encrypted text, it's decodes using json_decode and gets 'Hello World' string

**Questions**

- Is communication web-safe? Web-safe in sense, data which is being transmitted between SE.com and CE.com can be transfered in similar fashion as GET request?
- If someone tries to read transmitted data on-way of transmission, whether he can decrypt it, and see what it contains or not?

  Also, provide suggestions to improve security & communication.

  Help appreciated.

Comment: Most of this is fluff - if you're using SSL to encrypt the on-the-wire data, then you're reasonably secure against most snoopers and only large government agencies or math supergeniuses who can factor large primes quickly will be able to read your data.

Comment: @MarcB didn't get you regarding fluff?

Answer (score 1):

Implement client-side certificates. While using server-side certificates can prevent/deter interception of the message, it can't prevent someone spoofing SE from talking to CE in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can you please comment on communication thing too? Suggestion to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Two-Way SSL authentication](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v5r1/topic/com.ibm.itim.infocenter.doc/cpt/cpt_ic_security_ssl_authent2way.html&ei=0mCeT8-QBoXt0gHQtOmhDw&usg=AFQjCNHSJhui6D9h5Hz_uS-fCW0WilPcmg&sig2=YWFZXV3h-T5isOL50_Ja8Q).